# Where do I find my game IDs for Unity Ads?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ads, unityads

I was following a tutorial on YouTube and the game ID was shown in the `ADS` section of the `Services` tab. I cannot seem to find mine, however, in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot including the Services tab of Unity v2019.4.28f1 for Windows]

Comment: Its not the fact this is a noob question... Its the fact this is not likely to help anyone else in the future which makes this question less than optimal. Read [ask]

Comment: Sure sir I'll be careful next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Go To http://dashboard.unity3d.com/
2. Click the Monetize button
3. Select Project
4. Click Ad Units

Then you can check this link https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/unity/integration-guide-unity

[image: Reference Image]

Comment: Thankyou so much Sir, I can see the game Id's. Sorry again for this question. Will follow the stack overflow guidelines for asking questions in the future.